# With `iptables` does the chains order matter?

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

Does the **order** matter? for example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If so would `forward` be in the correct order to come second in this `iptables` rule chain if it's read chronologically or is this rather subjective?

Comment: It's totally wrong. The order of rules is important. Read the iptables tutorial, please.

Answer (score 1):

The order of `iptables` commands doesn't affect how the pre-defined chains are processed. The default chains `INPUT`, `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` aren't processed sequentially and a packet going through `INPUT` chain won't hit `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` chains, a packet going through `FORWARD` won't get into `OUTPUT` and `INPUT` chains etc. See [iptables tutorial](https://rlworkman.net/howtos/iptables/chunkyhtml/c962.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are messing the order of rules in one chain, which is important, with different chains. With your example it's irrelevant because rules in `INPUT`, `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` chains are processed for totally different packets.

But if you add rules to the same chain, then the order gets absolutely important:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

That way 1st rule to ACCEPT will be added 1st. Once a packet matches that rule, it is ACCEPTed and leaves the chain. I.e. the REJECT rule will never work in the example above as the packet will always first match ACCEPT rule.